# Avoid coalescing of ACTION_MOVE MotionEvents in Android

Tags: java, android, motionevent

I was trying to accurately read `ACTION_MOVE` deltas from a sequence of `MotionEvent`s in Android.

My tests with swiping a finger over the screen however suggest that after the initial `ACTION_DOWN`, several `MotionEvent`s are not delivered to the listener.  Only after a sufficiently large move is made, a `ACTION_MOVE` event is delivered with a relatively large delta.  After this first `ACTION_MOVE` event, all deltas are very small again.

Alternatively, one can also touch the screen (`ACTION_DOWN`) and slightly move around and no `ACTION_MOVE` event is delivered at all.

I understand that for many uses, having a certain move (in)sensitivity is beneficial.  However, is there a way to avoid coalescing of `ACTION_MOVE` events such that every small initial move is delivered?  Is there a threshold that can be set on the minimum distance between the `ACTION_DOWN` position and the first `ACTION_MOVE` position?

Here is some sample code:

```
private float lastX;
private float lastY;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

    final float y = ev.getX();
    final float x = ev.getY();

    final int hs = ev.getHistorySize();

    final int ac = ev.getAction();
    switch(ac)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            this.lastX = x;
            this.lastY = y;
            Log.i("TEST", "Down at " + x + "/" + y + " (History size="+hs+")");
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            Log.i("TEST", "Move at " + x + "/" + y + ": Delta="+(lastX-x)+"/"+(lastY-y) + " (History size="+hs+")");
            this.lastX = x;
            this.lastY = y;
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            Log.i("TEST", "Up at " + x + "/" + y + " (History size="+hs+")");
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

And the corresponding output:

```
Down at 376.0/259.0 (History size=0)
Move at 392.0/268.0: Delta=-16.0/-9.0 (History size=0)
Move at 394.0/268.0: Delta=-2.0/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 395.0/269.0: Delta=-1.0/-1.0 (History size=0)
Move at 394.0/268.0: Delta=1.0/1.0 (History size=0)
Move at 396.0/269.0: Delta=-2.0/-1.0 (History size=0)
Move at 399.0/271.0: Delta=-3.0/-2.0 (History size=1)
Move at 401.0/272.0: Delta=-2.0/-1.0 (History size=0)
Move at 403.0/273.0: Delta=-2.0/-1.0 (History size=0)
Move at 404.0/273.0: Delta=-1.0/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 405.0/274.0: Delta=-1.0/-1.0 (History size=0)
Move at 406.0/275.0: Delta=-1.0/-1.0 (History size=0)
Up at 406.0/275.0 (History size=0)
```

In other words, I want to avoid the large delta at the second line (-16/-9) but receive deltas in the order of 1 or 2 ...

I made tests on the Samsung Galaxy S2 and Note.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is it a deadband in movement or a dead TIME following an ACTION_DOWN, during which ACTION_MOVEs are disabled? Perhaps you might like to experiment to find out which.

Comment: you can get more points by using event.getHistoricalX/Y() methods

Comment: It is definitely a deadband in movement.  The same behavior can be observed either when (1) touching (`ACTION_DOWN`) and keep the finger steady and after some second start moving or (2) swipe over the screen w/o waiting.  The first `ACTION_MOVE` event has always the largest delta -- as if there was a **minimum delta required** before an `ACTION_MOVE` is reported after an `ACTION_DOWN`.

Answer (score 4):

I hate to break it to you, but this is entirely Samsung's fault and will only happen on a Galaxy S2. Basically they added a software touch threshold in the input driver for no real reason.

I once tried to convince them to remove the threshold, but they didn't seem to understand the problem and told me that is was *deliberate*! Despite this, they have fixed it in the Galaxy S3.

Fortunately it isn't a hardware limitation, so you can get around it if you have a rooted phone, or install a custom ROM.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Sorry I delete it from my channel since ... well do people still use Galaxy S2s?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MotionEvent in some apps and necer faced this issue.

If you using a SDK version > 4 then MotionEvent supports multitouch. I'm testing this on my apps and use a modiffied listener to get the touch events. Code bellow:

```
private static PointF touchScreenStartPtArr[] = new PointF[10]; 
private static PointF touchScreenStopPtArr[] = new PointF[10]; 
private static PointF touchScreenCurrPtArr[] = new PointF[10]; 

OnTouchListener onTouchListenerMulti = new OnTouchListener() { 

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 

        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK; 
        int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT; 
        int fingerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex); 

        switch (action) { 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: 
            touchScreenStartPtArr[fingerId].x = event.getX(pointerIndex); 
            touchScreenStartPtArr[fingerId].y = event.getY(pointerIndex); 
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: 
            touchScreenStopPtArr[fingerId].x = event.getX(pointerIndex); 
            touchScreenStopPtArr[fingerId].y  = event.getX(pointerIndex); 
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) { 
                touchScreenCurrPtArr[fingerId].x = event.getX(i); 
                touchScreenCurrPtArr[fingerId].y = event.getY(i); 
            } 
            break; 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 
};
```

--EDIT--

The result of running your code in device Huawei X5:

```
Down at 387.29388/247.27272 (History size=0)
Move at 387.29388/247.27272: Delta=0.0/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 387.29388/247.27272: Delta=0.0/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 387.29388/245.39589: Delta=0.0/1.876831 (History size=0)
Move at 387.29388/244.92668: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 387.29388/244.45747: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 387.29388/243.98827: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 387.29388/243.51906: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 389.01614/243.51906: Delta=-1.7222595/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 389.8773/243.51906: Delta=-0.861145/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 389.8773/243.04985: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 390.73843/243.04985: Delta=-0.861145/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 390.73843/242.58064: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 391.59958/242.58064: Delta=-0.861145/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 391.59958/242.11143: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 392.46072/242.11143: Delta=-0.861145/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 392.46072/241.64223: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 393.32187/241.64223: Delta=-0.861145/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 394.183/241.64223: Delta=-0.861145/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 394.183/241.17302: Delta=0.0/0.46920776 (History size=0)
Move at 395.04413/241.17302: Delta=-0.8611145/0.0 (History size=0)
Move at 395.04413/242.11143: Delta=0.0/-0.9384155 (History size=0)
Move at 395.04413/242.58064: Delta=0.0/-0.46920776 (History size=0)
Up at 395.04413/242.58064 (History size=0)
```

It looks like you may have another listener stealing events from this one.

I would suggest that you check your code (you need to a add a "return false" in the end) in a cleaning project, just to be confirm it.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Luis.  I understand the implications of multi touch.  However, I am considering here a simple "single touch" scenario where I have only one finger and it seems as if after the first touch, there is a minimum threshold on the move distance required before the first move event is fired.  I am trying to avoid this behavior, i.e., immediate reporting of any move independent of a threshold.

Comment: @msto You are right, it should not make any difference using single touch. I've tried your code in both emulator and a Huawei x5 device. It didn't show the issue you are reporting. I'm editing the answer to post the log.

Comment: Luis, this is indeed interesting!  Thanks for carrying out this test.  On which View element have you registered the event listener?  I used a plain and empty view spanning the entire view port.  Perhaps I have to rename this question slightly and make it specific to Samsung phones ...

Comment: I used a textView that fills all the screen. My device is running Gingerbread.